# Trying to fetch axios data with redux, and load it in a component using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

As the title says, but im unable to do so.
This is what I have done so far.

I have first of all created an actions.js file.

```
import axios from "axios"

export function loadPhones() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get("apiurl").then((res) => {
            dispatch(fetchPhones(res.data))
        })
    }
}

export function fetchPhones(phones) {
    return {
        type: "LOAD_PHONES",
        phones: phones
    }
}
```

This file supposedly per my understanding fetches the api if loadPhones is called.

Then we have the reducer file, with some default data in phones state, which I want to replace by the data received by the fetcher

```
let defaultState = {
    phones: {phone1: "sony" }
}

const mainReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    if (action.type === "LOAD_PHONES") {
        return {
            ...state,
            phones: action.phones
        }
    } else {
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
}

export default mainReducer;
```

And after that I have the store.js file, where the store is created with a middleware thunk to fetch the api with async

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import reducers from "../reducers/reducer.js"

let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default store;
```

After that I load up the store in the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './redux/store/store.js'


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And to finish with, i go to my component, and I load the data

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { loadPhones } from "./redux/actions/actions.js"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loadPhones: () => dispatch(loadPhones)
  }
}

function App(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    props.loadPhones(); //supposedly we fetch the data
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(props.phones)}
      {JSON.stringify(props.phones)} //this part wont show the fetch data
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

But everything files there. props.phones is always the default object, and useEffect doesnt seem to trigger loadPhones(), and anyway I dont think I need to use the useState in the app, if I can fetch directly from redux, but i dont really understand how to do so, im a bit lost

Can anyone lend a hand and check where is it failing? Afaik the axios fetch in the actions.js is never called.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a sample codesandbox, with request to some sample api like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ ?

Comment: @RosenDimov yess give me one second

Comment: I think I understood where's the issue, but l'd rather see a demo too.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-payne-v9sjn?file=/src/App.js @RosenDimov , i have used a mock api

Comment: You directly call dispatch when the setup happens. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dispatch` like this in your `mapDispatchToProps`:

`loadPhones: () => dispatch(loadPhones)`, so not calling dispatch upon setup but only when you use loadPhones.
But the real issue is that `loadPhones` is not called upon `dispatch`, check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-almeida-mg41j). It should be dispatched like that:

```
dispatch(loadPhones());
```

And btw you have some console errors, it's `onClick` instead of `handleClick`.

Comment: True Rosen, onclick doesnt make sense there since im not using it, i forgot to delete it. I have updated my App.js file with what you have written, and then I try to call it in useEffect. But the data of props.phones stays as the default one, without fetchi. So the fetch in redux isnt happening.

Comment: In fact I think that the action LOAD_PHONES is never called and i dont understand why

Comment: You're right, this is not a big issue, I updated my response with working sandbox. It was ```loadPhones``` not being called as a function in ```dispatch```. The confusion probably comes because ```loadPhones``` (the action) is a function which returns function.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, if you want to make an async call in redux, you should use [redux-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise). With this library you can call an async resource inside a `dispatch` to retrieve and store data in redux. The way you make async call in redux cannot works.

As an alternative, you could use [redux-axios-middleware](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware) that helps you to use promise in redux using axios. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zmqldx772) example. It helped me a lot.